# Squid 3.1: external_acl_type ttl won't work

Tags: squid, access-control-list, ttl

I have custom script for handling Squid3's **external_acl_type** and it works fine.

In this script (btw, its PHP) I turned on logging every request into the file.

As far as I know from [docs](http://www.squid-cache.org/Versions/v3/3.1/cfgman/external_acl_type.html) **TTL** value must provide caching positive answer from my script (string value **OK**) and should NOT call external script for time set as **TTL** value. 
But it don't! I see in my log lines with every request but not only 1 as supposed to.
Here is the line from *squid.conf*:

```
external_acl_type EXT_WEBSESSION ttl=3600 negative_ttl=0 children=10 concurrency=200 %SRC %DST %URI /usr/lib/squid3/squid_webacl
```

Could you please assist me?